# Size of the AUDIOFORMAT (WAVEFORMATEX) structure

Tags: c#, winapi, marshalling

There's struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct WAVEFORMATEX
{
    public ushort wFormatTag;
    public ushort nChannels;
    public uint nSamplesPerSec;
    public uint nAvgBytesPerSec;
    public ushort nBlockAlign;
    public ushort wBitsPerSample;
    public ushort cbSize;
};
```

`Marshal.SizeOf(WAVEFORMATEX)` says it's = 18

The Win32 `SendMessage` func returns size = 16
[image: 444]

Actual size is 13, and I can assume it's aligned at the size of 4, so the 16 looks correct.

Why `Marshal.SizeOf(WAVEFORMATEX)` says 18?

[image: 222]

Or, if 18 is correct, then why SendMessage returns 16?

Comment: ushorts are 2 bytes, and uints are 4 bytes. 5 ushorts plus 2 uints equals 18 bytes.

Comment: A `ushort` is 2 bytes and a `uint` is 4 bytes, so that struct is 2+2+4+4+2+2+2=18.  That would be the correct size it's been defined.  Where are you getting the other numbers?

Comment: `The Win32 SendMessage func returns size = 16` what does this mean?

Comment: I don't understand why you packed the structure. But as it happens that won't affect the size here. I guess your mistake is that you think ushort is a single byte. It's actually two bytes.

Comment: Which message are you talking about?

Comment: yes, you're all right, i'm stupid. i missed it.. ushot is not 1 byte.. my mistake.. but then why SendMessage says 16? maybe it's still set to WAVEFORMAT without EX??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, The size value 18 is correct because the size of `ushort` is 2 but not 1.

"*Win32 SendMessage func returns size = 16*"

The return value of [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) specifies the result of message processing, depending on the message sent, but not the size of it has sent.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/multimedia/wm-cap-get-audioformat

Comment: this is the sendmessage i use. waveformatex is the return struct. so if it's 18 then why it says 16?

Comment: yeah, it was my fault of course .. i stupidly assumed that ushot is 1 byte with 1 bit for sign. if I wrote WORD i would never missed it. but the return value 16 makes me confused anyway.

Comment: i have added comments to my question, pls, clarify the return value 16 then.. i'll set your feedback as the answer.. really 18 is not 16, right?

Comment: Depends on the return value of the function response the message. 16 can only  represent that the window `camHwnd` return the size of 16 to `SendMessage`.

Comment: Are you mean why it is still set to `WAVEFORMAT` without EX?

Comment: Seems like the default format in `camHwnd` is `WAVEFORMAT`, and you are not able to set it to `WAVEFORMATEX` with `WM_CAP_GET_AUDIOFORMAT `, but `WM_CAP_SET_AUDIOFORMAT `